# Want to create a schema but I am not a super user, therefore want to create schema as a superuser and the transfer ownership to current user?

Tags: postgresql

I have written a trigger that creates the schema, but it doesn't work because the super-user doesn't have create privileges. therefore i want to create schema from super user then transfer ownership to current and non super user inside trigger.

Comment: A trigger to create a schema does not make sense to me. Don't you mean a SQL script? Changing the owner of everything after creating the schema is tedious work. Personally I would `CREATE DATABASE newdb OWNER theuser;` then I can connect to newdb as theuser and create the schema.

Comment: "The super-user doesn't have create privileges": then it is no superuser. You'll have to add way more detail, plus some SQL statements and their results, to make this comprehensible and answerable.

Comment: If your user has create privileges on the database, they can create a schema. But I agree that a trigger to create a schema sounds strange. For which event is this trigger fired? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: A trigger creating a schema, is tricky, sounds like a huge accident waiting to happen. Are you really really really sure that you need this and that there is no other safe way to create a schema?

Comment: when the record gets inserted in department_details table then the schema of that department name should get generated, for this functionality i am creating schema with trigger. after insert on department_details

Comment: Why do you need different schema's for different departments? Because this could be just the first problem you're facing, because an empty schema is useless and you need tables, views and/or other objects as well. With a proper database model you don't need this at all. A department is just a record and it has an id and other data in other tables related to this department just use this id.